# Cakephp smtp emails not working

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp

I'm using Cakephp 2.6, I have configured smtp settings as follows in email.php,

```
 public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('support@mywebsite.com'=> 'MYWEBSITE'),
    'host' => 'hostingserver',
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

**In Controllerfunction**

```
    $email = "myemail";
    $Email = new CakeEmail("smtp");
    $Email->helpers('Html', 'Form', 'Text');
    $Email->emailFormat('html')
            ->subject('SUB: Notification')
            ->to($email)
            ->from('fromemail', 'MYWEBSITE')
            ->send('My message');
```

This is the **ERROR** I'm getting,

```
Internal error occured

Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 154 → CakeSocket->connect()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 95 → SmtpTransport->_connect()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1161 → SmtpTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP/Plugin/Admin/Controller/ClientsController.php line 816 → CakeEmail->send(string)
[internal function] → ClientsController->sendemail()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(ClientsController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(ClientsController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Where I'm missing configuration, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you respond when someone answer your question ? You din't do that on your previous question.

Comment: and is this happening in localhost ?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka Yep I just responded to my last question..

Comment: It is happening on my development server. Not on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because the SSL verification goes wrong - as the error message indicates.  Ideally, you should set up the SSL certificate, but you can disable ssl certificate verification as an alternative, although this is less secure.

You tried to disable ssl by adding the ssl array directly, but as [this post](http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/cant-send-an-email-on-cakephp3/1043/9) points out,  the ssl array needs to be wrapped in the context array like this:

```
'context'=>array(
    'ssl' => array( 
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
)
```

That fixed the problem for me.